# How to display Data of relative foreign key in Django html page?

Tags: python, django

I saw may answer but i don't know why in my page its not working can anyone help me to find the mistake.
`model`

```
class SchoollModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60 )
    image = models.FileField(upload_to = 'static/img' ,help_text='cover img')
    desc = models.TextField(null=True, blank=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class SchoolImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(SchoollModel, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.FileField(upload_to = 'static/img')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

`views.py` after importing all

```
def school_view(request , id):
    school_model =SchoollModel.objects.all().filter(id=id)[0]
    school_image = SchoolImage.objects.all()
  

    return render(request,'school.html' ,{'school_model':school_model,'school_image':school_image})
```

`school.html` i wanna display multiple image of school. i have inlined in admin. how we can get all the images that foreign-key to SchoolModel

```
{% for sch in SchoollModel.SchoolImage_set.all %}
<img style = 'max-height:14rem ;max-width:14rem;' src="{{sch.images.url}}" alt="image">
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: can anyone help me to solve ?

Comment: Your code looks correct so far. Can you please share your urls.py? Are you sure the school_model with the ID you're using exists and has images?

Comment: `urls.py`  path('school/<int:id>',views. school_view,name='school'),

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get all of the relations of a foreign key is to give it a `related_name` and use that.

```
class SchoollModel(models.Model):
    ...



class SchoolImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(SchoollModel, default=None, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.FileField(upload_to = 'static/img')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

You can then get all of the images related to a SchoollModel object using the `images` related name like this:

```
>>> schooll = SchoollModel.objects.first()
>>> images = schooll.images.all()
```

So in your view you can pass just the SchoollModel object to the template context:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def school_view(request , id):
    #school_model = SchoollModel.objects.all().filter(id=id)[0]
    school_model = get_object_or_404(SchoollModel, pk=id) #this is safer than your previous code

    return render(request, 'school.html', {'school_model':school_model})
```

And in your template:

```
{% for image in school_model.images.all %}
  <img style = 'max-height:14rem ;max-width:14rem;' src="{{image.images.url}}" alt="image">
{% endfor %}
```